# Can I execute unit test EcmaScript 6(2015) code on Headless Browser like Phantom Js ? If no, Can you mention any other way to achieve this?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, puppeteer, chutzpah

I am unit testing angular application.

I couldn't able to execute unit tests of code which are written using ES6 on Chutzpah.

What could be the possible solution?

***I need a stable way to achieve this.***

Comment: One way is to transpile your code before running tests. The pereferable way is to migrate to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: Can you please explain what transpile will do to the code.

Comment: Transpiling will turn es6 code into es5 code. Search for `babel transpile es6 Chutzpah` solutions.

Comment: Thanks Vaviloff. I will search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as **Vaviloff** didn't posted any answer but He told me in the comment section.

So,

Babel is the answer to this question.

Here is the link to [babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Babel is a Javascript compiler which transpiles the **ES6 code to ES5**.

Babel will change your ES6 syntax to ES5 and then you can unit test the output using Phantom js or Chutspah.

Comment: This is indeed what I wrote, but for a comment to become an answer it should contain more matter: for example, a configuration sample for Chutspah with babel enabled. Otherwise a reader in future will have to keep on looking for real solution.